# Trigger app on notification react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

hi everyone i have a taxi application build on expo 46,

Everything is working fine, I need a functionality when I get a new ride request the sound is playing in the background that's fine but I want to auto launch the app
i am using expo-notifications using firebase.

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from '../common/theme';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import { AppConfig } from '../../config/AppConfig';

export default async function GetPushToken() {

  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }
    const ref = {experienceId: '@' + AppConfig.expo_owner + '/' + AppConfig.expo_slug };
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync(ref)).data;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('messages', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: colors.RED,
      sound: 'default'
    });
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('bookings', {
      name: 'Booking notifications',
      sound: 'horn.wav',
    });
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('bookings-repeat', {
      name: 'Booking long notifications',
      sound: 'repeat.wav',
    });
  }enter code here
  return token;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify:

- platform
- app state (foregraund, background or killed app)

and do you have listeners for background notifications from firebase cloud messaging

Comment: Please check i have added

Comment: You need to open the app when the user tap the notification?

Comment: no i need automatically app open when notification come

Comment: Well you cannot open the app without user interaction

Comment: Like other apps are working, uber, indriver and careem. When the driver get a new ride app automatically open

Comment: My app is also running in background, ringing sound also but not opening, is it not possible like Whatsapp calls